# How to read a csv but separating only at first two comma separators?

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file. I want to read the file in R but use only the first 2 commas i.e. if there is a line like this in the file,

> 1,1000,I, am done, with you

In R I want this to the row of a dataframe with three columns like this

```
> df <- data.frame("Id"="1","Count" ="1000", "Comment" = "I, am done, with you")
> df
  Id Count              Comment
1  1  1000 I, am done, with you
```

Comment: I already achieved this by reading the file in and merging for those rows that have more than 3 elements in them. I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this.

Comment: If it is enclosed you can read "1","1000","I, am done, with you".

Answer (score 4):

Regular expression will work.

For example, suppose `str` are the rows you want to recognize. Here suppose your csv file looks like

```
1,1000,I, am done, with you
2,500, i don't know
```

If you want to read from file, just call `readLines()` to read all lines of the file as a character vector in R, just like `str`.

The technique is very simple. Here I use `{stringr}` package to match the text and extract the information I need.

```
str <- c("1,1000,I, am done, with you", "2,500, i don't know")

library(stringr)

# match the strings by pattern integer,integer,anything
matches <- str_match(str,pattern="(\\d+),(\\d+),\\s*(.+)")
```

Here I briefly explains the pattern `(\\d+),(\\d+),\\s*(.+)`. `\\d` represents digit character, `\\s` represents space character, `.` represents anything. `+` means one or more, `*` means none or some. `()` groups the patterns so that the function knows what we regard as a group of information.

If you look at `matches`, it looks like

```
     [,1]                          [,2] [,3]   [,4]                  
[1,] "1,1000,I, am done, with you" "1"  "1000" "I, am done, with you"
[2,] "2,500, i don't know"         "2"  "500"  "i don't know"
```

Look, `str_match` function successfully split the texts by the pattern to a matrix. Then our work is only to transform the matrix to a data frame with correct data types.

```
df <- data.frame(matches[,-1],stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(df) <- c("Id","Count","Comment")
df <- transform(df,Id=as.integer(Id),Count=as.integer(Count))
```

`df` is our target:

```
  Id Count              Comment
1  1  1000 I, am done, with you
2  2  1002         i don't know
```

Comment: I'm hoping that there is a more direct solution.

Comment: I am trying to avoid post processing on it after reading. I did use a workaround by reading the whole file then pasting together each row with more than 3 elements.

Comment: Suppose your csv file is named `data.csv`, you only need to call `readLines("data.csv")` to read all lines as a character vector into R. Then regular expression will take over.